# Weird Close Queue Audit Question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, disputed-review-audits

My understanding of any of the audit questions is to do some basic sanity checking to make sure the reviewer is paying attention.

Today I received this (https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5443949) as an audit which seems like a question that could go either way (as even the comments of the question attest). I marked the question as Close due to "Off Topic" for the "why isn't this code working" reason, but was told that the question was fine.

Why is this question OK? At the very least, why would it be a good audit question?

Comment: That seems like a "write my code for me" question to me.  It seems odd to me that this "audit" system is grading people on judgement calls, when that judgement can easily go either way in such cases.  I think the system is broken.

Comment: [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773)

Comment: If you VtC it the question should be removed as an audit candidate, stopping it from appearing again...

Comment: @JonK even a vote down will be enough to drop audit from CV / reopen queue, according to [official criteria](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/165773): "No close votes or downvotes, ever (only for close/reopen audits)"

Comment: @gnat Useful to know, thanks - I wasn't sure if the criteria depended upon which queue it appeared as an audit in. Still, I think that one *does* need to be VtC'ed.

Comment: @JonK I didn't know myself until a month ago when [I asked Shog about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/failed-a-reopen-question-audit-sure-looks-like-not-a-real-question-to-me/168372#comment771083_168372 "'No close votes or downvotes, ever' -- is this only for Reopen queue audits / only for some sites?")

Comment: @iStimple There does seem to be a mentality of "oh, this question is bountied so it must be good, here, have an upvote" amongst some of the SO community. Of course, I have no real evidence to support that claim, only my own observations...